# user authentication using servlets / glassfish : security concern

Tags: jsp, servlets, authentication, glassfish

I am developing **a user login authentication, using jsp/servlets and glassfish v3.**
Basically the jsp page has a form that calls the servlet. The servlet then checks username and password from the database and will authenticate based on that.
I am not experienced at all in security matters concerning user authentications (first time i build one using servlets), and i have some concerns that i would like to share:
- The "form" calls the servlet : /auth .
 If all is ok after the servlet processes the info, it will forward to a jsp page. However i noticed that i could put the url pointing to the servlet in the browser , for example : **localhost:8080/myapp/auth**,  and it will redirect to the jsp page without even having been authorized by the login mechanism.
 I wrote some if/else conditions in the servlet to prevent that from happening in case username/password were not found to be valid. However i am sure there is a better and professional way to do that, can anyone help with that? 
- And so, Is it possible to disable browsing directly to servlets in the browser? for example if a user puts in the browser url field : **localhost:8080/myapp/auth**, i want him to be denied access. Can this be done?
- In addition, when using :     `getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/something.jsp").forward(request, response);`
The forward is displaying my servlet name in the url path, ie if i was at: **localhost:8080/myapp/**, after this forward i get :**localhost:8080/myapp/auth** . is it possible to **not** display the "auth" part in the url after this forward?

**CODE:**
**the html form**

```
<form action= "auth" method = "POST">

    <tr>
    <td>Enter your name :</td>
    <td><input type = "text" name = "username"></td>
</tr><br>
<tr>
    <td>Enter your password :</td>
    <td><input type = "password" name = "password"></td>
</tr><br>
<tr>
    <td><input type = "submit" name = "submit" "></td>
</tr>

</form>
```

**My"auth" servlet's processRequest function:**

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    try {

            //Instantiate login Command
            String cmdPath = "DomainLogic.Commands.login";

            user usr = (user) cmdFactory.getInstance().getCommand(cmdPath).execute();

            if(usr!=null && usr.isLoggedIn())
            {
                request.getSession(false).setAttribute("ok", usr);
                getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/main.jsp").forward(request, response);

            }

        else
            response.sendRedirect("/index.jsp");

    } finally {}
}
```

**my "auth" servlet in web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>auth</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>bridge.auth</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>auth</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/auth</url-pattern>   
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Show us your code. A request is a request. The server has no way to know whether the user typed the URL or clicked on a link. Anyway, security through obscurity is always a bad idea.

Comment: I uploaded the code. How do you recommend i approach this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However i noticed that i could put the url pointing to the servlet in the browser , for example : localhost:8080/myapp/auth, and it will redirect to the jsp page without even having been authorized by the login mechanism.

Your major mistake is that you delegated both `doGet()` and `doPost()` to the one and the same custom method `processRequest()`. You should not do that.

The `doGet()` should be used to preprocess GET requests (as in, following a link/bookmark, entering the URL in browser address bar, etc) and the `doPost()` should be used to postprocess POST requests (as in, a submitted `<form method="post">`).

You need to change your `processRequest()` to be the sole job of `doPost()` method and let the `doGet()` do something else, e.g. displaying the login page. This will also instantly fix your other "problem" (this is actually not a problem, but a major misconception, I do also not see why that would be a security problem, expect from just bad code) of being able to access servlets by URL directly: just hide all JSPs including the login page in `/WEB-INF` so that you can only get the JSP by the servlet's `doGet()`. I'd only change the servlet's URL `/auth` to something more sensible towards the enduser such as `/login`.

#### See also:

- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - contains Hello World examples

Comment: Thanks a lot ! you're absolutely right, it was a big mistake of not taking care of the doGet() method. Yeah i named it auth and not login, because auth is a servlet that uses reflection and factory patterns to call a command named "login", which are then 2 different classes thus i didn't want to have the same class name twice, but yeah i might change auth to something else. Thanks for the information, i thought it might me be a security flaw to access servlet from URl, but since it's not then that's amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are duplicating features available in Java EE 6.  Why not used the JDBC realm and Java EE 6 [form-based authentication](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncbe.html#bncbq)?  Here's the JDBC realm [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2435/ggkuk.html).